# I'm trying to run a code on netbeans but it kept saying Command execution failed

Tags: java

cd /Users/merhawihaile/NetBeansProjects/mavenproject2; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 11.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath javaapplication1.Main" -Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec
Scanning for projects...

---

### Building mavenproject2 1.0-SNAPSHOT

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mavenproject2 ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/merhawihaile/NetBeansProjects/mavenproject2/src/main/resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mavenproject2 ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ mavenproject2 ---
File does not exist
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)

### at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 1.443 s
Finished at: 2020-02-19T19:58:04-05:00

### Final Memory: 9M/40M

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject2: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: Format the question properly.

Comment: @mersh, can you elaborate what were you trying to execute?